# Reusing PreferenceFragment with multiple preference files

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

**Scenario:**
My android application is acting as a server. There are N number of clients that are connected to the server. 
There is a set of settings for the clients which user can configure from the server (android app). so basically I am sending the user preferences over the socket to respective client.
The set of settings is same for all the clients but I need to maintain the the settings state for each client.
for example:

Set of Settings:

```
Settings 1
Settings 2
Settings 3
```

Now user configures the above set for 2 clients as follows:
For client1:

```
Settings 1 :true
Settings 2 :false
Settings 3 :false
```

For Client2:

```
Settings 1 :false
Settings 2 :false
Settings 3 :false
```

now in the android app when user selects the client1 then client1 specific set should be shown.

**Problem:**
I am not able to save client wise state of settings.

**My Expertise:**
I am a beginner in android programming.

**My progress so far:**
As per my understanding of the scenario I need to make client wise different-2 shared preference file.
I created a generic preference fragment for the set of settings. As the settings is same for all the clients so I am reusing the preference fragment.
I also tried to specify preference files dynamically for each client:

```
       SharedPreferences sharedPreference = context.getSharedPreferences(
                "<Here I dynamically specify prefs file name>", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

but it is not working.

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering to my own question, hope this may help someone in future:
We need to create different-2 preference files in this scenario. we can do this as follows:

```
getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("preference_file_name");
```

and later on to load that particular preference file

```
getSharedPreferences("preference_file_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```